# How to classify data to get a tree-like structure

Tags: python, string, data-structures

I'm trying to show information about applications and his datasources.
I would like to know how to get this type of output from my actual lines.

This my raw data, there are lines gotten from bash with a subprocess, the output could be modified because the subprocess commands is a combination of find, grep and cut.

```
Company1/application1 datasource=ds1
Company1/application1 datasource=ds2
Company1/application1 datasource=ds3
Company1/application2 datasource=ds1
Company1/application2 datasource=ds2
Company2/application1 datasource=ds1
Company2/application1 datasource=ds2
Company2/application2 datasource=ds1
Company2/application2 datasource=ds2
Company2/application2 datasource=ds3
```

And my desired output would be:

```
Company1
    application1 
        datasource=ds1
        datasource=ds2
        datasource=ds3
    application2 
        datasource=ds1
        datasource=ds2

Company2
    application1
        datasource=ds1
        datasource=ds2
    application2 
        datasource=ds1
        datasource=ds2
        datasource=ds3
```

**EDIT** Is there any way to go through the list to get this output?
Any concept for googleit? I don´t know how to start

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) creates missing values on the fly. I think it's perfect for your usecase.

Since your dataset is a a *dict* of *dict*s of *list*s, I used `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`. The rest is trivial

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = '''Company1/application1 datasource=ds1
Company1/application1 datasource=ds2
Company1/application1 datasource=ds3
Company1/application2 datasource=ds1
Company1/application2 datasource=ds2
Company2/application1 datasource=ds1
Company2/application1 datasource=ds2
Company2/application2 datasource=ds1
Company2/application2 datasource=ds2
Company2/application2 datasource=ds3'''

companies = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for line in s.splitlines():
    co_app, ds = line.split(' ')
    co, app = co_app.split('/')
    companies[co][app].append(ds)

for co, applications in companies.items():
    print(co)
    for app, datasets in applications.items():
        print(f'\t{app}')
        for ds in datasets:
            print(f'\t\t{ds}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a text file, or do you have the option to put the output in a text file? If so you could open the file, iterate through it's lines an then proceed to treat every line as a string that you will split.

Pseudo code:

```
fi = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
for line in fi:
    comp_application,datasource = line.split(' ')
    comp,application = comp_application.split('/')
```

Then after that you could put these in a dictionary something like so:

```
{'company1': {'application1': ['ds1', 'ds2']}}
```

Depending on the rest of your flow you would use something like [pretty print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) to output the code like you explained.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to use a tree.
You can do it quite simply with a class like this :

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,d):
        self.children = dict()
        self.depth = d

    def add(self,name):
        self.children[name] = Node(self.depth+1)
```

Here, each Node is an object with a depth variable and a dictionnary containing all it children

First you will have to represent your data as a clean list of lines, separated with spaces only

```
data = [
    "Company1 application1 datasource=ds1",
    "Company1 application1 datasource=ds2",
    "Company1 application1 datasource=ds3",
    "Company1 application2 datasource=ds1",
    "Company1 application2 datasource=ds2",
    "Company2 application1 datasource=ds1",
    "Company2 application1 datasource=ds2",
    "Company2 application2 datasource=ds1",
    "Company2 application2 datasource=ds2",
    "Company2 application2 datasource=ds3",
]
```

Now, using a bit of recursion, yon can sort your data easily:

```
def insert(t,branch):
    if len(branch):
        if branch[0] not in t.children:
            t.add(branch[0])
        insert(t.children[branch[0]],branch[1:])


t = Node(0)

for line in data:
    insert(t,line.split())


def display(t):
    if t.children:
        for c in t.children:
            print("\t" * t.depth + c)
            display(t.children[c])


display(t)
```

Output :

```
Company1
    application1
        datasource=ds1
        datasource=ds2
        datasource=ds3
    application2
        datasource=ds1
        datasource=ds2
Company2
    application1
        datasource=ds1
        datasource=ds2
    application2
        datasource=ds1
        datasource=ds2
        datasource=ds3
```

The advantage of this method is that you can use it with as many parameters as you want. Here you have three (company, application and datasource) but you can have more ...

I hope my code will help you !